# Fetchmail: Is it possible to retrieve remote folders and put these into specific local folders?

Tags: linux, email, fetchmail

I'd like to keep my Sent (Draft etc) emails in sync between a Zimbra hosted email provider's and my own server. Apparently fetchmail does not automatically download all folders, just the inbox. What is the best practice to keep both in sync?

Comment: I think you want IMAP.

Comment: I'm using fetchmail with imap, but I need to specify the folder option to sync certain folders and I'd like to sync remote folder Sent with local folder Sent_items for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If all you wanted is to sync with your imap folders on the server, you should use [OfflineIMAP](http://www.offlineimap.org/). This tool is able to synchronise email both ways, so for example, if you read the email on desktop, OfflineIMAP will mark that email as 'read' on the server during next sync or if you read email on the server, your offline desktop copy will be updated as 'read'.

I use it to keep an offline synced copy of my gmail locally. Don't have the configuration handy, but the documentation on the website should be pretty straightforward.